# Galois theory in reverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $K/F$ be a Galois extension. The fundamental theorem of Galois theory says that there is a bijection between subfields of $K$ containing $F$ and subgroups $H$ of $G$, where $G$ is the Galois group $\text{Gal}(K/F)$. This theorem lets you start with some arbitrary field, something you can just pretty much pull out of thin air, and learn something about it using group theory. However, the groups used in this group theory are not arbitrary. You have to restrict your attention to the Galois group, which depends on the field and some subfield.

My question is, how do you do this process in reverse? Start with some arbitrary group (in the sense that its existence doesn't depend on anything) and learn something about it using field theory?

Comment: The [inverse Galois problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem) is unsolved, which means there's basically no hope of doing this if you also require $F=\Bbb{Q}$. This is enough not-my-field that I don't want to make any statement more general than that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem you are intereted in is call the [inverse Galois problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem).

Every finite group is a Galois group, every profinite group is a Galois group. In general, it is quite hard, for a general group $G$, to say if $G$ is a Galois group or not. I would recommand JP Serre's "Topics in Galois theory" for an authorative reference and state of the art (a bit old, but it is good for a starter).

Comment: Not to mention that browsing "inverse Galois problem" will give you lot of all references, especially about "dévissage" techniques, allowing you to get the result (being a Galois group) for certain broader classes of group by actually having the result for a smaller class. (The passage from finite groups to profinite groups is typical.)